# creating new instance of domain class not saving

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Rather than save an editted domain class, I want to create a new instance of it with the changes I have enacted.

```
def update =
{
        def VariantInstance = Variant.get(params.id)
        VariantInstance.properties = params
        def NewVariantInstance = new Variant()
        //Now Assign Variant Instance new Values
        NewVariantInstance.Name = VariantInstance.Name
        NewVariantInstance.LocationID = VariantInstance.LocationID
        NewVariantInstance.aliases = VariantInstance.aliases
        NewVariantInstance.closeToBoundary = VariantInstance.closeToBoundary


        if (VariantInstance) {
        if (!VariantInstance.hasErrors() && !NewVariantInstance.hasErrors()) {
            println("no errors")
            try {
            NewVariantInstance.save()
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                println(ex.toString())
            }


            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'Variant.uniqueIdentifyingName', default: 'Variant'), VariantInstance.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }

}
```

However when I run through this A) A new version is not saved and B) the NewVariantInstance does not have an id.  Thoughts?

Comment: Your variable names are weird. In Java it's typical to use a capital first letter for class names, but lowercase variable names. This helps to differentiate between static and instance method calls.

Answer (score 2):

Your `VariantInstance` and `NewVariantInstance` are never validated, so `hasErrors()` will always return false. You need to switch from

```
!VariantInstance.hasErrors() && !NewVariantInstance.hasErrors()
```

to

```
VariantInstance.validate() && NewVariantInstance.validate()
```

It is likely that `NewVariantInstance` has a validation error so the `save()` is not successful.